# Yii, var_dump values in custom action method

Tags: php, yii

I have a submit button in my admin.php page.

```
echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('onclick' => 'js:document.location.href="Save"'));
```

in my controller I have added this code-

```
public function actionSave()
{
    echo 'hi';
    echo var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Now the problem is it displays only 'hi' message but does dump any values of my page.

Comment: Because you have to submit form. Remove that JS and use submitButton

Comment: Yes I have made changes but still does not dump values

Comment: Is your form method set to POST? try dumping $_REQUEST, maybe its passed over GET.

Comment: Yea the form method is set to POST. If I replace it with $_REQUEST, it says that  
The system is unable to find the requested action "document.location.href="Save"".

Answer (score 0):

Use CHtml::submitButton int your form instead of CHtml::button
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#submitButton-detail

Comment: I have changed it and its still does not dump my values

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is empty because you're not doing a POST request.
To make a POST request you must create a form with a submit button.